# Magento 2 C2C Platform with Offline Payment

Tags: magento2, extensions

I'm Looking for Magento 2 extension where users can post their products to buy/sell. Payment process will be done offline. Buyer & Seller can do discussion online via messaging.

So there are number of sellers & buyers. Admin has rights to approve/disapprove product of seller as well as his account.

Offline they will meetup exchange product & pay over there. Once product sold seller mark product as [Sold] on site.

Example: https://sg.carousell.com/

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are creating a marketplace.  The best option for this is the Unirgy Marketplace extension:
[Unirgy Magento Multi Vendor Marketplace](https://secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace)
Be sure to check out the available add-ons to the extension too as those may include some of the features you are looking for.